# AudioCache : Heap size Overflow! req Sixe: xxxx, max size: yyyy

Tags: android

I know this is duplicate of following many stackoverflow questions already
[Heap size overflow issues with sound clips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308850/heap-size-overflow-issues-with-sound-clips)

[AudioCache Heap size overflow issue req size: 1053184, max size: 1048576](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124026/audiocache-heap-size-overflow-issue-req-size-1053184-max-size-1048576)

[Android SoundPool heap limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296361/android-soundpool-heap-limits)

and many more like this, but I found none of answers actually address my problem. I am writing a world building game, and I have around 20 MB (which would definitely increase in future) which I have already compressed it to .ogg format. I need all those sound effects ready to be played. If I individually try to load them when they are required there is noticeable delay. So I had to load them at the beginning of the game but downside of this initial loading eats up all the heap and logcat is filled with these red error lines

> E/AudioCache(1070): Heap size overflow! req size: 1050624, max size: 1048576

I think many people might have tried this kind in their apps/games, Can any one shed some light how did you guys manage

Comment: same problem i had face in past and solve it just write this code on my anroid manifest xml file android:largeheap="true" on application.

Comment: @HCD: I already have that manifest entry done in my app, it doesn't help:( I am trying to find a better way to load/play so many sound effects