# Heap Size Memory Overflow! Eclipse-cocos2d-x

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I'm beginner of cocos2d-x and beginning porting to Android.
However I faced a problem, and searching for hours, none of solutions has work eventhough it's similar problem...

```
10-08 15:41:53.122: E/AudioCache(90): Heap size overflow! req size: 1052672, max size:
      1048576
10-08 15:41:53.122: E/AudioCache(90): Heap size overflow! req size: 1051136, max size: 
      1048576
10-08 15:42:15.036: E/dalvikvm(14086): Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager',  
      referenced from method xg.b
10-08 15:42:15.048: E/dalvikvm(14086): Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', 
      referenced from method xg.c
10-08 15:42:50.079: E/ActivityManager(251): ANR in com.sevenskylab.karapansapi 
      (com.sevenskylab.karapansapi/.KarapanSapi)
10-08 15:42:50.079: E/ActivityManager(251): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
```

I also set Android large heap to 'true', still doesn't work....

I don't think my audio files is the problem, It uses  .mp3 format.

The total files is 2.2mb, slightly smaller using .ogg 1.8mb

Can anybody help what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the below links..

[android soundpool heapsize overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428448/android-soundpool-heapsize-overflow)

[Android SoundPool heap limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296361/android-soundpool-heap-limits)

[Heap size overflow issues with sound clips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308850/heap-size-overflow-issues-with-sound-clips)

[AudioCache Heap size overflow issue req size: 1053184, max size: 1048576](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124026/audiocache-heap-size-overflow-issue-req-size-1053184-max-size-1048576)

Hope it'll help ..

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I'm a total noob when it comes to java :D I did read some of those links. I'm using C++ with NDK. Perhaps I'll give it a try...

Comment: Thanks I solved this by increasing heap memory size on eclipse. Refer to one of those links